# How to change BIOS supervisor password on TOSHIBA PORTEGE Z930 PT235

Tags: bios, passwords, toshiba-laptop

I have a TOSHIBA PORTEGE Z930 PT235 with a supervisor password registered in the BIOS. I don't know this password anymore.
Because of that I cannot change the boot sequence to install windows.

I've tried the following steps and they DIDN'T WORK to remove the supervisor password from BIOS:

1. disconnect the BIOS battery and the laptop battery (kept it disconnected for 4 hours) then reconnected back. I’ve looked and didn’t see any visible RESET jumper(s) on the mobo. Also I cannot find online the mobo diagram.
2. install TOSHIBA Supervisor Password Utility (Win 7 x64). When trying to change something in the application it says “Access denied” all the time. Cannot change anything with this application. I have admin rights with the win login account.
3. swap the old HDD with a new one (blank) and create a bootable USB with Windows on it, hoping the BIOS will go over all the bootable sequences if there is no OS installed on the HDD. BIOS remain on HDD and it didn’t go further to look over other bootable devices.
4. Flash the BIOS with a newer version – using ~ key down when power up.

Any other suggestions how to move forward will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you Run the Password Utility as Administrator? If it doesn't help, try [CmosPwd](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd).

Answer (score 0):

Toshiba's usually have a jumper contact near the ram modules to clear the password.